# initial loads up setting angular2

Tags: angular

I got another problem with the architecture of developing angular2 app.  I have a settings that I need to call via the web API.  I have a pipe that is depend on that settings.  Since the nature of the http.get is asynchronous, is there any way I could sort of stop the pipe load up while the call to web API complete?

example:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import {myPipe} from './myPipe'
import {settingService} from './setting.service'

@Component({
 template:'{{"setting.val1" | myPipe}}',
 providers:[settingService],
 pipes:[myPipe]
})

export class mainComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private _myService:settingService){}

  ngOnInit(){
       this._myService.getSetting() //this needs to complete first before the pipe executes
  }
}
```

as you can see, the string settings.val1 will be transformed via the pipe.  But the call of this._myService.getSetting() will need to be completed first before the pipe starts the transformation.  My question is how am I going to block the pipe from executing before the call of getSetting() complete?

Thanks,

**Update:**

SettingService code as follows:

```
export class SettingService{
  constructor(private _http:http){}

  public getSetting():void{
    this._http.get('someAPI')
    .map((result)=>{return result.toJSON()})
    .subscribe((data:any)=>{localStorage.setItems("settings",json.stringify(data))})
  }
}
```

so basically the service calls the web api and store it in localStorage.  The pipe will just need to parse the value from localStorage and call the object.

Meaning if the string got passed in as setting1.val1, the transform function in the pipe will be

```
transform(val,args){
  let settings = json.parse(localStorage("settings"))
  return eval("settings." + val); //in this instance, it will execute settings.setting.val1
}
```

Comment: If `this._myService.getSetting()` returns an Observable or a promise. you can use `AsyncPipe` that's what it is for.

Comment: @Abdulrahman the getSetting does return observable.  I just omitted out for the sake of brevity.  When you say using asyncPipe, how do i use it?  Do I just chain it with my custom one?

Comment: It would be better if you included the `getSetting` code in your question.But,  assuming you have an observable it'll be like this: `settings | async | myPipe`.

Comment: @Abdulrahman actually i'm not returning the observable.  That function is actually calling the http.get and store the result in localStorage.  You can check the updated code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class SettingService{
  constructor(private _http:http){}

  isLoaded:boolean = false;

  public getSetting():Promise {
    if(this.isLoaded) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return this._http.get('someAPI')
    .map((result)=>{return result.toJSON()})
    .do((data:any)=> {
      localStorage.setItems("settings",json.stringify(data))
      this.isLoaded = true;
    })
    .toPromise();
  }
}
```

```
class MyPipe {
  constructor(private settingService:SettingService) {}

  transform(val,args){
    return this.settingService.getSetting().then(_ => {
      let settings = json.parse(localStorage("settings"))
      return eval("settings." + val); //in this instance, it will execute settings.setting.val1
    });
}
```

In fact I would completely leave out `localStorage` from the pipe and instead only communicate with the `SettingService` and change the `SettingService` to only load data from the server if they are not stored in `localStorage` already or similar (don't know your requirements).

Comment: @Gunther the then in the pipe only return promise.  How do I get the actual value?

Comment: I expected Angular to handle that automatically, does it not?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't do that.  The return will be in the type of promise

Comment: I've made a little change to your code.  Available in plunkr here [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mi0oG2kHvSfpfndMpqdL?p=preview)

Comment: from my plunkr example you can see in the console, begin and end printed first before result.  Hence it throws an error.  i need to know how to get the result first before end

Comment: If it returns a `Promise` you need to use it like `<h2>Hello {{name | MyPipe | async}}</h2>` https://plnkr.co/edit/voZGFDsDNIII1XD4hRgQ?p=preview

Comment: ok so the async pipe is placed after myPipe.  Great.. that works.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, it processes the output of the previous expression.